# Mask based on two different Pandas Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, mask

Suppose I have two pandas dataframes:

```
In [1]: dates = pd.date_range('20170101',periods=6)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.empty([len(dates),2]),index=dates,columns=['foo','bar'])
df1['foo'].loc[0:2] = 'A'
df1['bar'].loc[0:3] = 'A'
df1['foo'].loc[2:6] = 'B'
df1['bar'].loc[3:6] = 'B'
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10,size=(6,2)),index=dates,columns=df1.columns)
print(df1)
print(df2)

Out [1]:
           foo bar
2017-01-01   A   A
2017-01-02   A   A
2017-01-03   B   A
2017-01-04   B   B
2017-01-05   B   B
2017-01-06   B   B 

            foo  bar
2017-01-01    5    3
2017-01-02    6    9
2017-01-03    5    9
2017-01-04    7    5
2017-01-05    0    2
2017-01-06    0    0
```

I'm interested in a creating a 3rd df populated with the max of df2 based on df1.  For example, the output would look something like this:

```
            foo  bar
2017-01-01    6    9
2017-01-02    6    9
2017-01-03    7    9
2017-01-04    7    5
2017-01-05    7    5
2017-01-06    7    5
```

Surely there's a succinct way to do this, right?

Answer (score 2):

One option is to concatenate the two data frames and assign a key to each one, transform the resulting data frame to long format, and then calculate the max grouped by the key and the column names:

```
(pd.concat([df1, df2], keys=["one", "two"], axis=1)
 .stack(level=1).groupby(level=1)
 .apply(lambda g: g.groupby("one",as_index=False)["two"].transform("max"))
 .two.unstack(level=1))
```

[image]

Comment: Wowser.  That's helpful and does get the job done, but it's less than succinct.  Does anyone have an alternative that requires less mental gymnastics?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the column values of `df1` to `df1` to get unique groups for which to `groupby`

```
df2.stack().groupby(
    df1.add(df1.columns.to_series()).stack()
).transform('max').unstack()

            foo  bar
2017-01-01    6    9
2017-01-02    6    9
2017-01-03    7    9
2017-01-04    7    5
2017-01-05    7    5
2017-01-06    7    5
```

To account for non strings

```
df2.stack().groupby(
    df1.astype(str).add(df1.columns.to_series().astype(str)).stack()
).transform('max').unstack()
```

Comment: This is pretty good.  It's not terribly robust though bc I believe it will throw a ValueError in the event the column labels are int rather than str.